# Discord bot gets an error becuase, class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I wanted to make a help embed in a channel, but when I started running it, it didn't work as I thought... I've looked at it, but I can't find any problems with it..
If there is someone that can help me, please do so.
I know this code is a little weird.
Packages I'm using:

```
@discordjs/rest 0.1.0-canary.0,
discord-api-types 0.22.0,
discord-buttons 4.0.0,
discord.js 13.1.0
i 0.3.6
npm 7.21.1
```

Here is the error I get when I use, node .

```
C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Carly Support Center\node_modules\discord-buttons\src\v12\Classes\APIMessage.js:9
class sendAPICallback extends dAPIMessage {
                              ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Carly Support Center\node_modules\discord-buttons\src\v12\Classes\APIMessage.js:9:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Carly Support Center\node_modules\discord-buttons\src\v12\Classes\WebhookClient.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

Here is the index.js

```
const { Client, Intents, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

//Importing Rest & api-types
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest')
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9')

//Loading Config
const config = require('./config.json');
const { default: discordButtons } = require('discord-buttons');
console.log('Config Loaded')
var owners = config.owners

//Ready Event
client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is Ready!`)

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        activities: [{
            name: config.status,
            type: "LISTENING",
        }]
    })
    
    //Registering Slash
    if (config.enable_slash) {
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(config.token)

        const commands = [{
            name: 'create',
            description: 'Replies with Help Embed!'
        }]
        
        try {
            console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.')
            
            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationCommands(client.user.id),
                { body: commands },
            );

            console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.')
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
})

/**
 * @author Emiluvik#8447 <https://github.com/Emiluvik>
 */

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    var SupportEmbed = 
    {
        author: { name: config.embed_content.title, icon_url: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: false, format:"png"}) },
        timestamp: new Date(),
        color: `0x${config.embed_content.color}`,
        thumbnail: { url: config.thumbnail ? config.thumbnail_url : client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, format: "png", dynamic: false}) },
        description: `\u200b\n1️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_1}\n\u200b\n2️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_2}\n\u200b\n3️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_3}\n\u200b\n4️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_4}\n\u200b\n5️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_5}\n\u200b\n> **None Of The Above**\nIf Your Question is not in the Above List.(Further Assistance)\n\u200b\n`,
        footer:{
            text: interaction.guild.name
        }
    }
    let button1 = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setEmoji("1️⃣")
        .setCustomId("button_one")

    let button2 = new MessageButton()
        .setEmoji("2️⃣")
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setCustomId("button_two")
        
    let button3 = new MessageButton()
        .setEmoji("3️⃣")
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setCustomId("button_three")
    
    let button4 = new MessageButton()
        .setEmoji("4️⃣")
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setCustomId("button_four")
 
    let button5 = new MessageButton()
        .setEmoji("5️⃣")
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setCustomId("button_five")

    let button6 = new MessageButton()
        .setLabel("None Of The Above")
        .setStyle("SUCCESS")
        //.setEmoji("‍♂️")
        .setCustomId("none_of_the_above")
    
    let buttonRow1 = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents([button1, button2, button3, button4, button5])
    
    let buttonRow2 = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents([button6])
    
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        if (!owners.includes(interaction.user.id)) {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "You aren\'t Authorized To use This Command!", ephemeral: true })
        }

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [SupportEmbed], components: [buttonRow1, buttonRow2] })
    }
    else if (interaction.isButton()) {
        let responseembed = 
        {
            author:{ name: config.title, icon_url: config.thumbnail ? config.thumbnail_url : client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, format: "png", dynamic: false}) },
            color: `0x${config.embed_content.color}`,
            description: null,
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer:{
                text: interaction.guild.name
            }
        }
        const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.log_channel_id)
        if (interaction.customId === "button_one") {
            responseembed.description = `\u200b\n**${config.responses.response_1}**\n\u200b\n`
            logchannel.send(`> **${interaction.user.username + "#" + interaction.user.discriminator}**(${interaction.user.id}) Used ${interaction.customId}\nTimeStamp: ${new Date()}`)
            // let invitecutie = new MessageButton()
            //     .setLabel("Invite Link")
            //     .setStyle("url")
            //     .setURL("Link")
            // let buttonRow = new MessageActionRow()
            //  .addComponent(invitecutie)
            //!If You Want Button in the Response remove // from the the Above 6 lines
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })//If you want to send link button add ,component: buttonRow after the ephermeral: true declaration
        }
        if (interaction.customId === "button_two") {
            responseembed.description = `**${config.responses.response_2}**\n\u200b\n`
            logchannel.send(`> **${interaction.user.username + "#" + interaction.user.discriminator}**(${interaction.user.id}) Used ${interaction.customId}\nTimeStamp: ${new Date()}`)
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })
        }
        if (interaction.customId === "button_three") {
            responseembed.description = `**${config.responses.response_3}**`
            logchannel.send(`> **${interaction.user.username + "#" + interaction.user.discriminator}**(${interaction.user.id}) Used ${interaction.customId}\nTimeStamp: ${new Date()}`)
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })
        }
        if (interaction.customId === "button_four") {
            responseembed.description = `**${config.responses.response_4}**`
            logchannel.send(`> **${interaction.user.username + "#" + interaction.user.discriminator}**(${interaction.user.id}) Used ${interaction.customId}\nTimeStamp: ${new Date()}`)
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })
        }
        if (interaction.customId === "button_five") {
            responseembed.description = `**${config.responses.response_5}**`
            logchannel.send(`> **${interaction.user.username + "#" + interaction.user.discriminator}**(${interaction.user.id}) Used ${interaction.customId}\nTimeStamp: ${new Date()}`)
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })
        }
        if (interaction.customId === "none_of_the_above") {
            responseembed.description = `**Go to <#${config.assistance_channel_id}> Channel and ask Your Questions.**`
            interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id).roles.add('856799419402813440')
            interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.assistance_channel_id).send(`<@${interaction.user.id}> Here you can Ask your Further Questions.`)
            logchannel.send(`> **${interaction.user.username + "#" + interaction.user.discriminator}**(${interaction.user.id}) Used ${interaction.customId}\nTimeStamp: ${new Date()}`)
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })
        }
    }
})

client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return
    if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return
    if (!owners.includes(msg.author.id)) return
    if (msg.content !== `${config.prefix}create`) return
    if (msg.content = `${config.prefix}create`) {
        await msg.delete().catch(() => {})
        let button1 = new MessageButton()
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setEmoji("1️⃣")
            .setCustomId("button_one")

        let button2 = new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji("2️⃣")
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setCustomId("button_two")
            
        let button3 = new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji("3️⃣")
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setCustomId("button_three")
        
        let button4 = new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji("4️⃣")
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setCustomId("button_four")
 
        let button5 = new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji("5️⃣")
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setCustomId("button_five")

        let button6 = new MessageButton()
            .setLabel("None Of The Above")
            .setStyle("SUCCESS")
            //.setEmoji("‍♂️")
            .setCustomId("none_of_the_above")
        
        let buttonRow1 = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([button1, button2, button3, button4, button5])
        
        let buttonRow2 = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([button6])
        
        const supportembed = {
            author: { name: config.embed_content.title, icon_url: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: false, format:"png"}) },
            timestamp: new Date(),
            color: `0x${config.embed_content.color}`,
            thumbnail: { url: config.thumbnail ? config.thumbnail_url : client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, format: "png", dynamic: false}) },
            description: `\u200b\n1️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_1}\n\u200b\n2️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_2}\n\u200b\n3️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_3}\n\u200b\n4️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_4}\n\u200b\n5️⃣ ${config.embed_content.question_5}\n\u200b\n> **None Of The Above**\nIf Your Question is not in the Above List.(Further Assistance)\n\u200b\n`,
            footer:{
                text: msg.guild.name
            }
        }
        return msg.channel.send({ embeds: [supportembed], components: [buttonRow, buttonRow2] })
    } else return
})

client.login(config.token).catch(() => console.log('Invalid Token.Make Sure To Fill config.json'))
```

And here is the config.json..

```
{
    "token": "Token",
    "status": "cs!help",
    "prefix": "cs!",
    "enable-slash": true,
    "owners": ["468053162729799700"],
    "embed_content": {
        "title": "Carly Support",
        "color": "FFA500",
        "thumbnail": true,
        "thumbnail_url": "profile.png",
        "question_1": "How do I invite Carly?",
        "question_2": "How do I setup Carly?",
        "question_3": "Carly isn't responding",
        "question_4": "How do I make a bug report?",
        "question_5": "How do I suggest a command to Carly?"
    },
    "responses": {
        "response_1": "If you type: [prefix]invite, Carly will you give an invite link!",
        "response_2": "Carly is already set and done! If you wish to change the prefix\nto Carly, type ?prefix [prefix].",
        "response_3": "If Carly isn't responding, it is because, the MongoDb pass failed\nto connect, or it's because the bot is shutting down.",
        "response_4": "If you join the (support center)[https://discord.gg/nB84Fn6VGd]\nyou can make a report a bug!",
        "response_5": "If you join the (support center)[https://discord.gg/nB84Fn6VGd]\nyou can make a suggestion!"
    },
    "log_channel_id": "880869600298954802",
    "assistance_channel_id": "880869600298954802",
    "assistance_role_id": "880870840030351520"
}
```

I've tried to install diferent npm packages, but it still wouldn't work.
So here I am asking for help.

Comment: This question needs more clarity as to what your issue is. Try to paste the error area into the question, instead of your entire `index.js` file.

Comment: Like that? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error using discord-buttons: "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767240/error-using-discord-buttons-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discord-buttons library currently only supports v12 of Discord.js and relies on a class from that lib that doesn't exist anymore in the latest version 13. There's also [an issue](https://github.com/discord-buttons/discord-buttons/issues/134) to update the package to support v13 but it doesn't look like that's going to happen anytime soon. If you'd like to use the package, either downgrade your djs version to v12 or use something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to fix the problem yourself.

Hope this helps ;3